# Sometime unable to login with domain account although username and password are correct

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, domain-controller

Every morning , when I try to login to my computer  I can't login and the message appears `User name or password are incorrect`, although username and password are correct. Once I login with the "Administrator" account, then I can login with my own account.

What I have seen, when administrator login for the first time, network connection icon shows, it's disconnected, and after 2 or 3 seconds network is connected.

Comment: What does the event log say (System-NW details; Security- Logon Failed)? Are you trying to connect via local or domain account? I guess it's domain. When you mentioned "Administrator" account, is this a local or domain account? You added many tags like domain, DC, AD - is "my computer" from your first sentence a basic computer joined to domain or are you referring to a server? If you are referring to a server, is it AD joined server or a DC directly?

Comment: Thank for your attension, I connected login is domain user login account. Administrator mention also domain administrator account. Yes, I added many tags , beacuse I don't know what should be "tag", sorry for that.